# Django, passing get query has a value to filter query, calls get query twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have get query which is passed as a value in filter query ,when running the code get query is called twice.
#get query

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(    
            user=self.request.user.email, project=self.request.org_id)
```

#filter query

```
LeaveApproval.objects.filter(approver=employee)
```

#dbCallLog
 `SELECT ••• FROM "leavetracker_employee" WHERE ("leavetracker_employee"."project_id" = 'f5b10d49-9056-4faa-b95a-251f998a724f'::uuid AND "leavetracker_employee"."user_id" ='rajini@gmail.com') LIMIT 21`

2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.
Why employee call is duplicated twice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

to prevent duplication can do the following

```
employee_id = Employee.objects.get(    
            user=self.request.user.email, project=self.request.org_id)
LeaveApproval.objects.filter(approver__id=employee_id)
```

as employee repeated to time